# UITextField input not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app in Xcode where a screen comes up asking you to multiply 2 numbers, and then you put the product in a text field and if the answer is right there will a button that is gray will turn blue.

The problem is is that it wont work even if I'm sure of my answer while testing the app it wont work, the button will stay grey and the app will think the answer is wrong, please anyone help me and tell me what is wrong with my code!

```
    var firstNumber = arc4random()
    var secondNumber = arc4random()
    @IBOutlet weak var AnswerButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var OutcomeNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func textFieldEditingDidChange(_ sender: Any) {
        print("textField: \(textField.text)")
        if ValidatePassword(text: textField.text!) {
            AnswerButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            AnswerButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func AnswerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("you may enter")

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    func ValidatePassword(text: String) -> Bool {
        var result = false
        if text == ("(\(firstNumber*secondNumber))") {
            result = true
        }
        return result

    }

    @IBAction func GObutton(_ sender: Any) {
        OutcomeNumber.text = "\(firstNumber)×\(secondNumber)"
        firstNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
        secondNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
    }

    @IBAction func GoMedium(_ sender: Any) {
        OutcomeNumber.text = "\(firstNumber)×\(secondNumber)"
        firstNumber = arc4random_uniform(50)
        secondNumber = arc4random_uniform(50)
    }

    @IBAction func GoHard(_ sender: Any) {
        OutcomeNumber.text = "\(firstNumber)×\(secondNumber)"
        firstNumber = arc4random_uniform(100)
        secondNumber = arc4random_uniform(100)
    }


        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AnswerButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is on this part:

```
func ValidatePassword(text: String) -> Bool {
    var result = false
    if text == "(\(firstNumber) *  \(secondNumber))" {
        result = true
    }
    return result

}
```

Between `*` and `\(secondNumber)` are two spaces. When you try with text `(1 * 3)` this function returns `false` but with `(1 *  3)` returns `true`

On the other hand, is best to use `Regular Expressions` to evaluate this.

The result in `Playground`
[image]

Comment: i tried removing the space but nothing changed, how do I use regular expressions, sorry im new to Xcode, if you could link me to an article or tutorial or just tell me here i would be extremely appreciative

Comment: I added an example on playground and works perfect. To learn about `Regular Expressions` you can use this https://regexone.com

Answer (score 0):

Mhergon is right. The problem is your function that validates the answer. Your code structure and the way you compute and accepts the answer is not in the right way. But looks good for a starter. Anyways, take a look at your `ValidatePassword` code.

Try your code in the **PlayGround** of Xcode.

Take a look at this example taken from your code, just different variables:

```
let x = 3
let y = 4

print("(\(x) *  \(y))")
```

That prints `"(3 *  4)"`

Now, change the print to this:

```
print("(\(x*y))")
```

It now prints the correct computation and answer which is **12**.

**EDIT**

You are answering the wrong question. Generate the random numbers before printing them out to the user.

You can check this sample I made. To check for shorter codes as well. :)

https://github.com/glennposadas/TextFieldGame-iOS

Comment: I also tried changing the code to what you suggested still no difference, do you think there might be anything else i could try change?

Comment: Quick tip, do you know how to debug? Put some *breakpoints* in your `if-else` of your `textFieldDidChange` and in your `if`of your `ValidatePassword`. Then print their values, like `po textField.text!`. In that way, you can check easily, one-by-one the values of your variables, and how they're changing.

Comment: im really confused, can someone test out the code and see what needs to be changed so that the text field could accept variables, it works the first time but after that i doesnt.

Comment: i tried removing one of the "=" signs in if text == "(\(firstNumber) *  \(secondNumber))" , but it gave me an error saying " cannot assign value: 'text' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: @JiryesHaddadin check my edited answer. :) You may want to choose this answer if it helps you. No need for regex.

Comment: Sorry, see the edited answer for the link. @JiryesHaddadin. Again, you are answering the wrong question. Generate the random numbers before printing them out to the user.